# Unit testing dependent methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I would like to unit test a method on a class I have made, but this method requires another method to be called first. Example:

```
// This would work
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass(mockDevice);
myClass1.Run(myDatastructure);
myClass1.Stop();

// This would throw an InvalidOperationException
MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(mockDevice);
myClass2.Stop();
```

`Run` is starting an operation on a hardware device, and `Stop` is of course trying to stop that operation (sending a reset-command and starting a timeout-timer).

Anyway I would like to test various post-conditions of calling `Stop`, but I would like NOT to have to call `Run`, because I am testing `Stop` - not `Run`! I would like something like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockDevice);
myClass.Stop();
Assert.IsTrue(mockDevice.ResetCalled);
```

So far I only see one possible solution, and that is to create a `TestableMyClass` that inherits from `MyClass`, that makes it possible to set the right internal state of the `MyClass` instance before calling `Stop`. The problem with this solution is that I have to change my `MyClass`-implementation to have protected members instead of private members, and I *don't* like the idea of having to change the implementation in order to test it!

Should I use this solution, is there an error in my design, or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I see it, you are already testing `Stop` in the two ways in which it can be used (with and without a running operation). As long as the `mockDevice` is doing its job, it seem to me that you're testing it reasonably. Ideally you should be able to verify the commands sent to the device etc (which most mock frameworks will make simple).

Comment: So you think it is okay to just call Run, Stop, Assert?

Comment: Yes, I think so. And also worth calling Stop without Run to check the required exception is thrown. Ultimately, it is not valid to call Stop without Run first...

Answer (score 5):

In this situation, personally, I would have two tests for this:

1. Test without Run() being called first. I would test if it really throws the exception. I would also test if the post conditions are what I expect them to be.
2. Test with Run() being called first. I would test only the post conditions, that I expect.

Those are the only two important uses of the method that have different behaviors - therefor I would test them both.

EDIT:
I understand, why you don't want to call run, before stop - you think that if run fails, the test, that is supposed to only test stop method will most likely fail as well.

However, I would assume, that you also have test for the run method. This means, that when the tests, that test the behavior of run method pass - stop method tests must pass as well. If the run method tests fail, then the results of run method tests are undefined - they may or may not fail.

So, I'd say, don't be afraid to call other dependent methods in your tests, but make sure you test those dependent methods in separate tests.

Comment: I am already testing the Stop-method that throws an exception, but I see your point!

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but I'm going to accept Marc Gravell's answer, as he was first :-)

Answer (score 1):

It won't help your immediate problem, but I tend to favour mapping state to type rather than having objects with different modes.

```
IdleDevice idle = new IdleDevice(mockDevice);
RunningDevice running = idle.Run(myDatastructure);
running.Stop();

// This would not compile, as IdleDevice has no Stop method
IdleDevice idle = new IdleDevice(mockDevice);
idle.Stop();
```

If you can't compile impossible situations, you don't need to test them.

Comment: I like that design! I will consider using that, but for now I will just test Stop followed by Run. Thanks